# How to compile a python/shell script ? (to hide informations)

Tags: python, shell, ftp

I would like to compile a script to launch with linux.

Indeed, I use babun (shell linux for windows) and I have a scritp with password in clear text...

I would like to hide this to use it.
I use python or shell script because it's very easy and quick to do containing linux commands.

Thank you.

```
import os
os.system("truecrypt /a /p passeword /q /e /v \"C:\Users\blabla.tc\"")
```

And I use ftp ... (to do a backup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the password into the file. This is the only way to hide a password.

If you only want to obfuscate it, so that nobody stumble accross it by accident:

```
import subprocess
password = 'cGFzc3dvcmQ='.decode('base64')
path = "C:\Users\blabla.tc"
subprocess.Popen(['truectypt','/a','/p',password,'/q','/e','/v',path]).communicate()
```

Comment: But even then, it would be trivial to get to it, if somebody were to get the base64encoded password.

Comment: Thank you, I have to code in C or another compiled langage if I want really hide the passeword... (for a truecrypt command line or sftp command line..)

Comment: No, for a compiled language it's the same. If I know, you use truecrypt, it's 10 seconds for me, to get your password.

Comment: Really ?! It surprises me. Can you tell me more ? I didn't know it's possible to get informations about compiled software ! If I use a sftp command line too ? (It's only truecrypt or every command lines ?)

Comment: As soon as you have a call to an external interface, you can set a breakpoint there and look, what information is transferred. Compiled software is only a little bit harder to read than scripts, sometimes.